# Sales reports showing $0

Tags: error, sales, reports

I'm having a bit of a weird problem. I'm trying to run reports for 2 of my magento stores and I'm getting $0 values in all sales reports. It will show the proper order quantities as well as how many items are being ordered but any dollar amount is zeroed out. I've refreshed lifetime statistics several times but with no luck. These stores are both fairly new and this is the first time I'm trying to run reports.

I have other stores running on older magento versions without issue. The two in question are on 1.9.2 and 1.9.1

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth checking that you have set up your currencies correctly in the admin and that you have a value in `base_to_global_rate`. I have had a similar problem in which this not being set is multiplying by 0 
The settings are in **system->manage currency->rates**